# getline(); in C don't stop input

Tags: c, input, getline

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
     
char split_text(){

    int bytes_las;
    int antal_bytes = 40;
    char *min_strang;

    printf("Enter text: ");

    min_strang = (char *) malloc (antal_bytes + 1);
    bytes_las = getline (&min_strang, &antal_bytes, stdin);

    printf("\n%s",min_strang);

}

   
int main()
{
    printf("   MENU:\n");
    printf("1) Split text\n");
    printf("2) Upper case to lower case\n");
    printf("3) Lower case to upper case\n");
    printf("4) Remove character\n");
    printf("5) Add character\n");
    printf("6) Replace character\n");
    printf("7) Statistics\n");
    printf("8) Sort text\n");
    printf("0) Exit\n");
    
        
    int i;
    char option;

    for(i=0; i<5;i++){
                
        
        printf("I want: "); //assign the option number
        option = getchar();
        switch(option) {                //use function assigned to what option

        case '1'  :
                printf("do for 1\n");
            split_text();
                break;
    
        case '2'  :
                printf("do for 2\n");
            break;
    
        case '3'  :
                printf("do for 3\n");
            break;
    
        case '4'  :
                printf("do for 4\n");
            break;
    
        case '5'  :
                printf("do for 5\n");
            break;
    
        case '6'  :
                printf("do for 6\n");
            break;
    
        case '7'  :
                    printf("do for 7\n");
            break;
    
        case '8'  :
                printf("do for 8\n");
            break;
    
        case '0'  :
                printf("do for 0\n");
            exit(0);
    
        default :   
            break;
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is my function in a separate file. When calling it the function reads and I get the correct "Enter text: " output. However, there is no limit. When I push Enter key nothing happens just keeps taking input.

I'm on Ubuntu and using C only, no compiling errors.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps, you call `split_text()` in a loop?

Comment: Where do you return the string read to the caller?

Comment: @chqrlie there is no return i think. It should free that memory block after he's done with it.

Comment: @Michi: of course!  The OP should also test `bytes_las` to verify if input was read at all. He is not giving us enough context to investigate his problem.

Comment: @Sroy for me works [fine](http://ideone.com/yqQgnO)

Comment: I call this function in a while(1) loop from a switch case.

Answer (score 0):

You can end input in various ways, one could be:

```
ssize_t read;
read=getline(&min_strang, &antal_bytes, stdin);

if(read < 1){
    printf("Input ends here\n");
            return 1;  
    }
```

This ends when there is no more to write.

Comment: "This ends when there is no more to write."? how exactly it ends, from stdin?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
        option = getchar();
```

as input is usually line buffered, you enter e. g. `1\n`, i. e. you put two characters in the input buffer, of which you consume only the `1` with `getchar()`, and the `\n` stays in the buffer. When thereafter `getline()` is called, it gets the next character from the buffer, and this `\n` immediately causes `getline()` to return an empty line.
To rectify this, consume the menu input up to the `\n`, so that `getline()` has to read new input:

```
        option = getchar(); if (option != '\n') while (getchar() != '\n') ;
```